# Error when running rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to setup an ror app but I keep getting this error. Any ideas as to what may be causing the problem?

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/projects/testproject/lib/tasks/more_tasks.rake:3
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/projects/testproject/Rakefile:10
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: You should give more info about your setup: OS, db and what exactly did you do and what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: You might want to verify that you have the database gems and software installed properly. eg > gem -v mysql or > gem -v sqlite etc, depending on what database software you plan to use. And then is the underling software installed? eg > which mysql or > which sqlite3 etc...

Comment: It looks like the first line of your stacktrace is missing, it should look something like `LoadError: no such file to load -- foo`. It would really help us figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

List your gems version, type "gem list" in the console and you will get a list of gems installed with there versions, kindly paste that list here so that the error could be identified. Thanks